# Why we should not sleep after Asr?

Tags: salat

I've heard that it's sunnah not to sleep or nap after asr but nobody can tell me why.  Why we should not sleep after Asr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is No authentic hadith which proves that sleeping after Asr prayer is wrong. So whoever told you this, just ask him to bring proof from Quran and Sahih hadith.

for mode details you can go here: http://islamqa.info/en/2063